# NAudio - Can not Replay the played sound

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

Here is my code:

```
var w = new WaveOut();
var wf = new Mp3FileReader(new MemoryStream(Resources.click));
w.Init(wf);
w.Play();
```

It will play the audio once, If I `Play` it again, it will not play it. If I want to make a new Mp3FileReader every time to play the audio, the memory usage of my program will grow more and more.

I just need to use one `WaveOut` and play the sound in multiple threads as I can. possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, we can reset the memory stream position to play the audio again without memory usage:

```
audio = new Mp3FileReader(new MemoryStream(Resources.click)); // audio is global
player = new WaveOut(); // player is also global
player.Init(audio);
```

then whenever we need to play the sound we will do this:

```
audio.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
player.Play();
```

Comment: should mark this as an answer then! :)

Comment: @DenisSchaf I know, but after 24 hours I can do this. now 1 hour remaining :)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code in a using block:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Resources.click))
{
   var wf = new Mp3FileReader(stream);
   var w = new WaveOut();
   w.Init(wf);
   w.Play();
   //w.Dispose(); //maybe? maybe not?
}
```

This will make sure the the object is disposed properly

Edit:

new day new hope!
as described here:
https://csharp.hotexamples.com/de/examples/NAudio.Wave/WaveOut/Play/php-waveout-play-method-examples.html

```
 public void PlaySound(string name, Action done = null)
 {
     FileStream ms = File.OpenRead(_soundLibrary[name]);
     var rdr = new Mp3FileReader(ms);
     WaveStream wavStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(rdr);
     var baStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(wavStream);
     var waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
     waveOut.Init(baStream);
     waveOut.Play();
     var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
     bw.DoWork += (s, o) =>
                      {
                          while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                          {
                              Thread.Sleep(100);
                          }
                          waveOut.Dispose();
                          baStream.Dispose();
                          wavStream.Dispose();
                          rdr.Dispose();
                          ms.Dispose();
                          if (done != null) done();
                      };
     bw.RunWorkerAsync();
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but again the memory is growing more and more...

Comment: Added a .Dispose(), please try

Comment: and now the sound will not play at all :)

Comment: silence... my favorit sound... :)

Comment: another edit and my last attempt

Comment: The same result, the memory usage will grow...One vote for your good try ;)

Comment: @InsideMan last_chance_final_final_2.resp
Seems like the dispose is in fact nessessary but it disposed the object before playing the sound at all this function  i put in the edit should do the trick. Ofc you ll have to modify it to play a memory stream but that should be an easy thing :)

Comment: I have found a very small and clean solution Denis :) you can give it a look my friend.